# how to locate the built product (app) in Xcode 4x programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I know the location of the DerivedData folder that Xcode creates once I build the project. Is there a way to locate the app present in the below location programmatically?
The folder under DerivedData/MyApp-xxxxx is renamed every time I clean the project.
Is there a way to record the location in the env of shell just after the app is built.

`/Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-afepqzfgigqcxicavejbdehhtbox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` environment variable should be what you are looking for. If you want to dig into the bundle, you can determine it's name with `WRAPPER_NAME`. Something like `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(WRAPPER_NAME)` would be the the path to the app bundle.

> /Users/macadmin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-afepqzfgigqcxicavejbdehhtbox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app

[Build and Product Location Build Settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW108)